# Find mp4 files with certain file naming in subfolders and extract frames from it every second with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, macos, ffmpeg

I have a folder with several subfolders that contain mp4 files.
I want to extract frames of those mp4 files every second, but **only** of mp4 files that **contain** **"abc" in the file name**. 
Those frames should be saved in a separated "images" folder with a naming that has frame count of the corresponding video.

The file structure with folder and subfolders and how I imagine the file naming of the frames:

```
|main_folder
|
├── folder1 
|   ├── abc123.mp4
|   └── xyz123.mp4
├── folder2
|   ├── abc456.mp4
|   └── xyz456.mp4
|       ├── folder2.1
|          └──abc183.mp4
|          └──xyz183.mp4
├── folder3
|   ├── abc789.mp4
|   └── xyz789.mp4
├── images
    ├── video1-frame1.jpg
    ├── video1-frame30.jpg
    ├── video1-frame60.jpg
     ...
    ├── video2-frame1.jpg
    ├── video2-frame30.jpg
    ├── video2-frame60.jpg
```

So far I only have this and can't get any further :(

```
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -vf fps=1 -q:v 3 "images/${i%.*}_frames%d.jpg"; done
```

I am missing the search in the subdirectories and the search for mp4s that only have "abc" in their file name.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You can't tell which video any image came from and you said you wanted the frame count in the filename.

Answer (score 1):

try with `find`:

```
find /home/phillip -type f -iname '*abc*.mp4' | xargs -I %% ffmpeg -i %% -vf fps=1 -q:v 3 "images/${i%.*}_frames%d.jpg"
```

Comment: yes that already works pretty good except the frames are being overwritten every time a new video is being processed.

Comment: any leads to how I can prevent the files from overwriting each other?